# jquery ui autocomplete custom display if no results returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, popup, jquery-ui-autocomplete

how can I display a custom popup if no results are returned ?

I have managed to display a "no results" response if the term returned no results

```
    response:function(event, ui){


        if(!ui.content.length){

            var noResult = {value:'',label:'No results'};
            ui.content.push(noResult);

        }
    }
```

but how can I display a custom popup. I am trying to display a window with necessary fields to add the item if it doesn't exist.

Comment: So instead of modifying the `ui.content`, you can just show your own popup normally, if you mean to show the popup right at the position of the autocomplete dropdown (replace the dropdown), then it may be more complicated.

Comment: yep, that's what I'm trying to do, to alter the ui popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so actually it was very easy...

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    .....
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    //customizeaza selection list-ul 
    return $("<li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<input type='text' maxlength='3' size='3' /><a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.den_prod + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul)
};
```